# Saving data from Flask webapp into database

Tags: python, database, flask

basically I have a page where all of my items are listed. These items contain string informations, such as address, price, ... I want to enable my users to save those items that they like so they can find them easilly in their page for saved items. I thought I could send the data stored in the item through POST method, but I dont know how to do it just by using a button.

This is how the items look on the page: [Two items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKufI.png)

The items are created in a loop, which goes through the dataframe and for each ID creates an item.  Here is the html code for that:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% for i in range(data|length) %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <small class="mr-2"></small>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ data.LOCATION[i] }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="{{url_for('/dashapp/', ure=data.UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER[i])}}">{{data.UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER[i]}}</a></h2>
              <small class="price">{{data.RE_PRICE[i]}}</small>
            <p class="article-content">{{ data.ADDRSS[i] }}</p>
          </div>
            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                <right>
                    <div class="media-body pt-5">
                        <form action="{{ url_for('saved') }}" method="POST">
                            <button class="btn-outline-info" type="submit"
                                    value="">Save</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </right>
            {% endif %}
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The data are sent through get method from my routes python file.

Is it possible to do it this way or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these:

1. In your button, you are not sending any value, set this attribute to the value you wish to send.

```
value = "{{ data.ADDRSS[i] }}"
```

and set a name for your button:

```
name = "saveData"
```

2. Make sure your *"{{ url_for('saved') }}"* handles the passed parameters in the right way. In your route, you could:

```
value = request.form.get('saveData')
#your sql query to save 'value' in database
```

Comment: And when i want to pass all the attributes from the data that I have there? Should I pass it as an array? In that case, I dont know how to handle the values one by one. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Passing multiple values properly comes into the jquery domain. Lots of questions on it already. If you want to achieve it using only HTML, two hacks:
1) Create a 'form' tag and subsequent 'input' tags with type='hidden' and values that you want to pass. Or,

2) Play with the DB. Instead of passing multiple values, pass just the id that can fetch the other values from the database and process them in backend.

You may search, "Pass multiple values on html button click" for answers.